# Python check if an argument was passed in by position or by keyword

Tags: python, parameter-passing, args, keyword-argument

What is a cleaner way to check if an argument was passed in by position or by keyword?

I am cloning and overriding functions under certain circumstances. The signatures of the overridden functions may grow over time, so I want something I won't have to change later, that I can use to extract only the couple of parameters I care about and ignore all the rest.

For example, the function call may look like this:

```
foo("bar", "baz")
foo(arg1="bar", arg2="baz")
```

Both are valid. If I am using `args` and `kwargs` to catch all the parameters, I have to figure out which one it ended up in. So far I'm doing this:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs): 
    arg1 = kwargs["arg1"] if "arg1" in kwargs else args[0]
    arg2 = kwargs["arg2"] if "arg2" in kwargs else args[1]
```

I feel like there has to be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: If you define your function with `def foo(arg1, arg2):` both ways of calling it will work

Comment: it seems you do not actually want to be using `args` or `kwargs` here but intend on expecting a param named `arg1` and `arg2` - so you should include them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    argnames = ["arg1", "arg2"]

    argdict = dict(zip(argnames, args))
    argdict.update(kwargs)

    print(argdict)


foo("bar", "baz")
foo(arg1="bar", arg2="baz")
```

Both give the same:

```
{'arg1': 'bar', 'arg2': 'baz'}
{'arg1': 'bar', 'arg2': 'baz'}
```

Then if you really need you can do `arg1 = argdict["arg1"]` etc, but you might as well just use a dictionary rather than extract into named variables.

*(Using string constants `"bar"` and `"baz"` here, rather than `bar` and `baz`, for sake of a self-contained example, but it is not dependent on them being strings.)*